# excel: comparison between hours

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this worksheet to compare two hours with a condition and shows me a result.

If the value inserted in cell is less than the sum of two other hours, the conditional should warn me that I need to insert a bigger value.

I had wrote the formula below:

```
=IF(X4>(U4+$T$7);"The value is ok";"Insert a bigger value")
```

The following image represents cells affected on my worksheet:
[Cells affected by formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3oYhX.png).

As you may see my Excel is in Portuguese therefore the "SE" function is the same as "IF".

The X7 cell with "7:00:00" only represents the sum that I want to compare just to check if the result was correct.

Anyway, as you can see [in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQwub.png) the result is "Insert a bigger value" when actually, 17:00 (5 PM) is bigger than 7:00 (AM). Is there any way to solve this mistaken result?

All my cells are formated from "General" to "Hour".

Comment: In your screenshots you have the opposite formula (`<` vs `>`).

Comment: @msitt sorry for that, I'll edit with the correct screenshots. I changed the formula after took them. Now I inserted the correct ones.

Answer (score 1):

use the hour function like this 
if(hour(X4)